# how to print no blur content over a blurred div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blur

I have a webpage in which a black rectangle is the background over a background wallpaper. The black rectangle is blurred out. I want to print a NON BLURRED content such as tables and thumbnail pictures OVER this blurred out black rectangle.

In this example, I am printing hello on top of the blurred black rectangle. but the hello is also blurred. how do I not blur the H3 tag? I have the HTML and the CSS i am using.

Below is the code.

```
<div class="blackRectangle">
   <div class="noBlur">
      <h3>HELLO</h3>
   </div>
</div>


.blackRectangle {
background-color: black;
opacity: .7;
top: 15px;
width: 1870px;
height: 900px;
position: absolute;
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
}


.noBlur {
    top: 30px;
    width: 1870px;
    height: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    -moz-filter: blur(0px);
    -o-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
 }
```

Comment: Can you just remove the non-blurred content from the blurred div? like: http://jsfiddle.net/po1v1k7k/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a blurred rectangle at z-index -1 and a non blurred rectabgle at z-index 1. So the non blurred rectangle will be placed over the blurred rectange and so its contents will be displayed clearly.

**HTML**:

```
    <div class="blurredRectangle">
    </div>

    <div class="nonBlurredRectangle">
       <div class="noBlur">
         <center> <h3>HELLO</h3></center>
       </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
    .blurredRectangle {
        background-color: black;
        opacity: .7;
        top: 15px;
        width: 1870px;
        height: 900px;
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
        -moz-filter: blur(5px);
        -o-filter: blur(5px);
        filter: blur(5px);
        z-index: -1;
        }

    .nonBlurredRectangle {

        top: 15px;
        width: 1870px;
        height: 900px;
        position: absolute; 
        z-index: 1;

    }

    .noBlur {
            top: 30px;
            width: 1870px;
            height: 900px;
            position: absolute;
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) !important; 
            -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
            -moz-filter: blur(0px);
            -o-filter: blur(0px);
            filter: blur(0px);
     }
```